# Is there a way to fetch url for google sheets from a different spreadsheet using apps script?

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to create a log for all the PDIR reports that are generated in our company. For this purpose, I have written an apps script code that brings forth a format from our master sheet when a product part no. is typed. After filling in the information it allows the user to press the submit button that transfers this PDIR to a PDIR database where all the PDIRs are being stored. Now, what I want to do is, add a feature to the submit button that automatically creates a log for the PDIR report. I have attached the format here for reference. I want to find a way to extract the URL of a particular sheet and add the link in the log next to the invoice, so my employees do not have to waste time finding different invoices and can just search for the invoice no. and have a link ready to take them to it.
Long story short, I want to find a way to get a URL of a sheet from a different spreadsheet using apps script.

[image]

Comment: Do you want to search the sheets and get the URL?

Comment: Yeah, that was the idea. I found a way to do it now.
I am not sure it is the best way or the cleanest way to do it, but it works fine. 
I saved the URL of the spreadsheet in which I save all my PDIRs and copy-pasted the URL without the sheetID in a whole column, let's say column A. Then I used Apps script to find the sheet ID of the particular PDIR and paste it in Column B. In column C I added a simple Concat function to get the full URL of a particular sheet in the spreadsheet

Comment: Would you please add the method in a little detail as an answer to this question so that others can get the knowledge too.